# Changing the icon of Google Maps marker while it's selected

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to change the icon of a map marker only while it's selected.

I implemented GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener class in my Fragment class.

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

....

  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {   
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.placemarker_pressed));
    return false;
  }
}
```

It changes the marker icon when clicked. How can I set it back to the original icon when it's unselected?

Comment: Seems you need some kind of `onTouchListener()` instead of `onClickListener()` so that you can track the type of the action performed over the marker. Check the docs to see if there exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Implement also the **GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener** interface and create a private variable to store the current selected marker:

```
private Marker mSelectedMarker;
```

Then:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {   
    if (null != mSelectedMarker) {
        mSelectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.placemarker));
    }
    mSelectedMarker = marker;
    mSelectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.placemarker_pressed));
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
  if(null != mSelectedMarker) {
    mSelectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.placemarker));
  }
    mSelectedMarker = null;
}
```

Comment: if more than one marker is selected before clicking the map, only the last selected marker is restored.

Comment: In that case, you can create list of `markers` and unselect all of them.

Comment: I've updated the code in the onMarkerClick() method. So if there is already a marker selected then you change its icon first back to normal and after it you can update the newly selected marker icon as well.

Comment: I have four markers with four different icons. If I click one It should be selected with a particular icon and If I click another marker then the previous one should be deselected and the current icon should be selected with its particular icon and so on. Could you please help me? @Blehi

Comment: But this not works after resume fragment and as google says we should not keep reference to markers. After resume there is some problem with mSelectedMarker and can not update it after any action.